# How to get the string array string[ ] with checked options of a checkboxItem in Google Forms through Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api, google-forms

As said in  [Class ItemResponse](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item-response#getResponse())

> For CheckboxItem questions, this returns a String[] array containing the responder's choices. The order of the strings in the array may vary.

I have a function that imports a Google Form answers. It has various items, some are checkbox, some paragraph. Those answers are setted on a spreadsheet.

The problem with the function is that for the items that are checkbox (multiple checks available) only imports one checked answer, and I need them all.

So I tried the following code, but the ver response isn't an array as the developers site says, or I am wrong:

```js
function leer() 
{
  //Definições iniciais da planilha
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); 
  
  var DB = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("REPXT").getRange("A2:D");
  var datos = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("REPXT").getRange("A2:D500").getValues();
  
  var base = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Base de datos REPXT");
  
    //Obter dados do formulário
  for(var i=0;i<SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("REPXT").getMaxRows() +1; i++)
  {
    if(datos[i][3]!="Importado"&&datos[i][2]!=""){
    
      var idg= datos[i][2]
      
    var form = FormApp.openById(idg);
    var formResponses = form.getResponses();
          
    var quant_resp = formResponses.length;
    
    
      //Buscar todas las respuestas
      for( var j = 0; j < quant_resp ; j++ )
      {
        //Obter dados do formulário
        var linhaform = formResponses[j];
        var linharesponses = linhaform.getItemResponses();      
        //Inserir no BANCO R2 - NOMBRE - e na aba AUX_LEER
        var inicio=   base.getLastRow() + 1 ;   
        
        base.getRange(inicio, 2).setValue(datos[i][0]);

          var l=3;
        
        for (var k=0;k<linharesponses.length;k++){  
          
          var itemResponse = linharesponses[k];
          
          base.getRange(inicio, l).setValue(linharesponses[k].getItem().getTitle()); 
          
          if(itemResponse.getItem().getType()== FormApp.ItemType.CHECKBOX){
           var response = itemResponse.getResponse();
           
           for (var m = 0; m < response; ++m) {
            
             
            base.getRange(inicio, l+m+1).setValue(response[m]);
             
           }
            l=l+1+chkItem.getChoices().length;
          }
          else  { base.getRange(inicio, l+1).setValue(linharesponses[k].getResponse());
                l=l+2;
                }
          
          
        }
        SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("REPXT").getRange(i+2,4).setValue("Importado");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Can you help me obtain all options checked on the checkboxItem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As a simple modification, if your script is modified, how about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- `chkItem` of `l=l+1+chkItem.getChoices().length;` is not declared. So I think that an error occurs at this line.
- In the for loop, an array is directly used. So please replace `response` with `response.length`.

  - I thought that this might be the reason of your issue.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
for (var m = 0; m < response; ++m) {


  base.getRange(inicio, l+m+1).setValue(response[m]);

 }
  l=l+1+chkItem.getChoices().length;
```

To:

```
for (var m = 0; m < response.length; ++m) { // Modified
  base.getRange(inicio, l+m+1).setValue(response[m]);
}
l=l+1+response.length; // Modified
```

If I misunderstood your situation and this was not the result you want, I apologize.